# How to set role on the registration form programmatically

Tags: users, forms

I'm trying to create multiple registration forms with a role assigned to each.

It seems that my default value for the role is not keeped, but it works with other fields

Here is my code

```
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($account, 'mycustomdisplay');
$form['account']['roles']['#default_value'][] = 'mycustomrole';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in a form alter hook, not after the form has already been built.

```
function module_form_user_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($condition) {
    $form['account']['roles']['#default_value'][] = 'mycustomrole';
  }
}
```